# How to Enable a .NET Web Service to Receive Large Amounts of Data?

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl

How do I enable a .NET Web Service to Receive Large Amounts of Data ?

I have a .NET Web Service which should receive several large files and save them in a directory on the local hard disk. The program (running on another computer on the same network) that tries to call the Web service receives the error: "Line is too long".

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Luis.

**CODE:**

**METHOD:**

```
Public Function ReceiveFiles(ByVal FileContents As String,
  ByVal FileInfo As List(Of String),
  ByVal listBinaryFileContents As List(Of Byte()),
  ByVal listStringFileContents As List(Of String)) As String() Implements IReceiveFiles.GetDataReceiveFiles
```

...

**DATACONTRACT:**

```
<OperationContract()> Function GetDataReceiveFiles(ByVal FileContents As String,
  ByVal FileInfo As List(Of String),
  ByVal listBinaryFileContents As List(Of Byte()),
  ByVal listStringFileContents As List(Of String)) As String()
```

**WEBCONFIG:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Show us some code, and probably your WCF configuration or web.config as well.

Comment: Have you tried what's mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded